# IoC container and dll memory management

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

I'm working on a server project and the server has a few different, independent layers and a few singleton classes. And I use the `SimpleInjector`, an IoC container, all across the layers. The full, executable example source code is available at  https://github.com/DamonJung/TestAdvanture001.. ( *It's unnecessarily lengthy because I was trying to reproduce a different problem there.* )

I access the `Singleton` from `Main` method directly and indirectly from the IoC container.

```
// Use case in Main
.
.
using Impl;    

static void Main(string args[])
{
    .
    .
    // Singleton.Instance address = 0x0301f001 for example.
    var context = Singleton.Instance.GetContext();

    // SimpleInjector
    // Singleton.Instance address inside of the dependency = 0x0408f023 for example.
    var di = Container.GetInstance<ISomeInterface>();
    var contextFromIoC = di.GetContext();
    .
    .
}
```

I expected the `Singleton` should be instantiated only once and the static instance should have the exact same memory address in the application, no matter where it's being invoked from and no matter how it's constructed ( by `Main` or the IoC container )

However, as the console output is saying, it didn't work that way. The `Singleton`'s `Instance` shouldn't have been instantiated more than once. But they ended up having a different address on their own.

[image]

If my shallow understanding serves me right, the executable loads the dll into its own memory, and once the static member is created, the variable can be accessed throughout the `AppDomain` region.

Isn't [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members) confirming the fact about static variables, isn't it?

> **Static Members**
>
> A non-static class can contain static methods, fields, properties, or events. The static member is callable on a class even when no instance of the class has been created. The static member is always accessed by the class name, not the instance name. **Only one copy of a static member exists, regardless of how many instances of the class are created**. Static methods and properties cannot access non-static fields and events in their containing type, and they cannot access an instance variable of any object unless it is explicitly passed in a method parameter.

I was in search for the relevant read in `SimpleInjector's` documentation and found none. Reading about dynamic linking library and its memory management doesn't come right at me ( I shall be reading it further and over and over again anyway ! )

- How a program treats dlls in terms of memory management
- If IoC container is the scene behind, how `SimpleInjector` treats the dependencies when they are registered via `Container.Register();`

Above items would be my ultimate questions.

Answer (score 4):

Two instances are created because your code creates two instances.

The first one is created by the following code

```
public class Singleton
{
    public static readonly Singleton Instance = new Singleton();
    // ....
}
```

and the second one is created when you register your type to `SimpleInjector`

If you want an instance to be created only once you could use a private constructor

```
public class Singleton
{
    static Singleton()
    {
        Singleton.Instance = new Singleton();
    }
    public static Singleton Instance { get; }

    private Singleton(){ 
    }
}
```

This way only the `Singleton` class create itself.

To register your singleton in SimpleInjector you can use the `RegisterInstance` method :

```
container.RegisterInstance<Singleton>(Singleton.Instance);
```

By the way it is more common to let the container manage instances by itself and not rely on static property which could indicate that you are using a [service locator](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) which is a common anti pattern.

If you want to let `SimpleInjector` manage the instance you should use

```
container.RegisterSingleton<Singleton>();
```

This way `SimpleInjector` will create only one `Singleton` instance for the container.

See [Singleton lifestyle in the `SimpleInjector` documentation](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetimes.html#singleton-lifestyle)